# Equivalent GUI components Swing

Tags: java, user-interface, components

I have the following question: given a Swing GUI application (source code included), how can I ascertain that two components (e.g: JButtons, JList, etc) are equivalent (in the way that the same user code is executed for the same event generated on them).

My opinion is that first of all they'd need to have the same Listeners in the same order for all available events (I'm talking only about listeners added by the application itself), and then those listeners' code must not depend on the source of the generated Event (so no "Action Command" or e.getSource() should be called in their code).

This is for a research project regarding GUI applications I'm working on, I'm trying to study how you could reduce the number of GUI test cases by detecting equivalent components. If you have any thoughts on this (maybe I'm not taking something into account) please share them.

Thanks.

Comment: If exactly the same thing happens in the application, but different code is used, this is probably a symptom of poor programming. If the same code is used, it's trivial. Are you trying to find examples of poor programming? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I feel that this depends on your definition of "equivalent". By your definition, this means that "the same thing happens in the application when they generate their events".
But by "same thing", does this refer to the users perspective or the programmers perspective?

If its the former, then the question is redundant, since the user merely needs to check if the different actions lead to the same visual outcome to determine if they are equivalent. However, this is requires further thought- it might be possible that the immediate visual outcome is the same for both widgets, but in the long term, the actions might not be "equivalent" for the user. e.g. you press button A, you observe A; but if you make a list selection B, you observe A again, but also, some non-noticeable event B might happen which is not detected by the user. In the long run, this could affect things. So equivalence from a users perspective might be a tricky issue.

The latter case is harder to analyse. One way could be, as you mentioned, they share the same Listener i.e. the same method is used to handle both widgets. They could alternatively use different listeners, and perhaps even different methods, but if both methods essentially follow a similar logic or purpose, they might be "equivalent". However, this might be case specific and might be quite a nuanced topic (to compare methods).

Another idea: You might also choose to run experiments over various different tests and inputs on the widget and derive some statistical value to assign a certainty measure to your comparison (e.g. these widgets have are equivalent for over 80 percent of the provided inputs). This might apply when comparing text inputs for e.g. JTextArea and JTextField.

Your assumptions might also have a bearing on your definition of equivalence. e.g. assuming these inputs, A and B are equivalent.

These are just a few of my thoughts and opinions. After all, its a research paper. Hope I've provided some food for thought.

**EDIT**

I am of the opinion that the detection of the event itself is a trivial detail. Its how the event is handled which is important. Essentially your question boils down to: is there some way of comparing the event handler for a particular event. Honestly, I'm not sure how this can be done (compare stacks maybe, check for code redundancy, check for is-a relationships). I honestly don't know how such comparisons can be done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've edited the question, hopefully it's a bit less ambiguous now.